# Why foreign key is added to my table

Tags: ef-code-first

I have a model:

```
public class QuestionRevision
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int IdEditor { get; set; }

        public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, I have additional column in `Tags` table, called `QuestionRevision_Id`.

Of course one tag could be assigned to many questions, so it's not what I need.

What annotation I need to add to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I've added at Tag class:

```
public virtual List<QuestionRevision> QuestionRevisions { get; set; }
```

and at QuestionRevision:

```
public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

and now I have table TagQuestionRevisions, so now it's work how I want.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem, however I don't understand your answer.  Would you please update this to include more detail?  I want to have many tags that are shared.  I realize that I'll need to store a mapping between Products (my use case) and tags.  Thank you!